# Why might it be necessary for a nefarious secret society who kidnaps key people over a long period of time, manipulating history, to keep them alive?

Tags: magic, time-manipulation

In a world where there are two secret societies vying for control, one nefarious and the other altruistic, the former kidnaps key individuals throughout history (maybe by time manipulation or magic) and keeps them alive in a hidden realm. Since the abduction is for some unknown vile purposes, what might be reasons for the captors **out of some necessity** keep the captives alive?

The idea is about some natural law or consequence that would require or
necessitate preservation of life.

Comment: Questions about the motivations of characters or organizations are not permitted on this site.

Comment: This is not question about motivation. The question states "out of some necessity"

Comment: For clarification, is this society based in the future where the individuals' historic importance is already known, and via some means "reaching back in time" to kidnap them from the past?  Or are they just some long-lived society who have existed for a long period of time and been, every few years/decades/etc, kidnapping people ("in the present") whenever they believed it was appropriate?

Comment: The society exists throughout the timeline but has some limited means of communication within the society that allows for each member to communicate with all other members whether they are in the future or the past.  So there is no need to "reach back" or "time travel"  as their operatives exist through out the history they are trying to influence.

Comment: Necessity is still a motivation. As the storyteller and worldbuilder you can construct countless scenarios that make a particular course of action necessary. Such an open ended and subjective question is not suitable for this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Key individuals keep the timeline on track

Time travel is very possible, and can result in massive changes. However, key figures act as a buffer against this. If someone causes a massive change, a key figure can be sent back with temporal cloning to reset the timeline to a chosen result.

Temporal changes take a certain amount of time to ripple forward to destroy secret society machinations, and if you can send back Abraham Lincoln or Hitler or whoever you can reset the timeline to the original. This only works if you have the original figure on hand though.

If they lost these figures then their rivals could radically change the past in their favor and put humanity on a better track. They can't have that.

Answer (score 2):

**They are constrained by divine rules.**

> Job 1:12 And the Lord said unto Satan, Behold, all that he hath is in
> thy power; only upon himself put not forth thine hand. So Satan went
> forth from the presence of the Lord.

Satan messes with Job a lot, but Satan is not allowed to kill Job.  So too your societies.  Both of the societies are governed by supernatural beings.  These beings have rules that they must follow.  One is that there are particular people they may not kill.

There are other rules less comprehensible to humans,  Maybe also incomprehensible to the supernatural beings that follow them.

Answer (score 1):

This is from other story I read but adjusted.

What if your civilization is controlled by certain unknown power, and always led to ruin after it reached certain level of advancement.
So there are people knowing this (since your base allows for magic and time manipulation) but helpless to counter the force , so they control the key people and since they are fueled by people's fear and all, they try to hamper the civilization progress while amassing population to enhance their power, since more people = more power for them.

and since the trigger for the reset is the advancement of civilization and no one can change it, it feels like it's a loophole for them to take advantage hence, the necessity to keep controlling the world from behind the stage, amassing power, and maybe adding one or more personnel to their numbers in preparation to fight the unknown force, with help only from clues left behind from previous cycles.

Answer (score 1):

### Assassination is immoral

Most people in your secret society are unwilling to become murderers, or to capture victims and deliver them to a murderer for the purpose of being murdered. Just like in real life.

You're looking for

> some natural law or consequence that would require or necessitate preservation of life

So, try these on for size:

- killing is immoral
- no organization can survive or accomplish its goals if it is unable to attract and retain talent

If members know that these historical figures are being taken out back and shot, many members will stop participating, and may even turn on the group.

So, the group merely kidnaps the historical figures and keeps them in a private zoo. Any member who has doubts about the fates of captives can have those doubts dispelled immediately by being shown the zoo.

This allows the group to maintain the moral high ground. Rather than butchering their way to utopia, they can honestly say they are just paralyzing the forces that would stand in their way. They can even say that they'll release all their captives once the utopia is achieved. Leaders in the group will probably predict that the captives will come around to the group's views once they can see the results.